# Plone: Creating new Page fails "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dates'"

Tags: python, plone

I just installed Plone on my Centos 5.5. I was able login via the admin-account and create new users. But when I try to create a new page I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 446, in __call__
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 31, in _call
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 240, in _exec
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 180, in pt_render
Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 80, in pt_render
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
Warning: Macro expansion failed
Warning: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'macro'
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 522, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 583, in do_setLocal_tal
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
URL: file:/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.2-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/calendar_macros.pt
Line 12, Column 4
Expression: <PythonExpr date_components_support_view.result(inputvalue, 0, starting_year, ending_year, future_years)>
Names:
{'container': <PloneSite at /reeple>,
 'context': <ATDocument at /reeple/portal_factory/Document/document.2010-12-24.9331499294 used for /reeple>,
 'default': <object object at 0x2ad1b9a18ae0>,
 'here': <ATDocument at /reeple/portal_factory/Document/document.2010-12-24.9331499294 used for /reeple>,
 'loop': {u'field': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x1bc9b9d0>,
          u'fieldset': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x1d396c90>},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {'args': (),
             'state': <Products.CMFFormController.ControllerState.ControllerState object at 0x1ccdb2d0>},
 'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x1d452ec0>,
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://82.165.145.121:8081/reeple/portal_factory/Document/document.2010-12-24.9331499294/atct_edit>,
 'root': <Application at >,
 'template': <FSControllerPageTemplate at /reeple/atct_edit used for /reeple/portal_factory/Document/document.2010-12-24.9331499294>,
 'traverse_subpath': [],
 'user': <PloneUser 'pascalklein'>}
Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 49, in __call__
__traceback_info__: date_components_support_view.result(inputvalue, 0, starting_year, ending_year, future_years)
Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
Module plone.app.form.widgets.datecomponents, line 50, in result
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dates'
```

Any suggestions? CentOS 5.5 has the Python Version 2.4. So I'm not sure if that causes the issue.

Comment: It is not my code. This is just the error message of the CMS.

Answer (score 4):

Plone 4 requires python 2.6, so it won't work with python 2.4. See http://plone.org/documentation/faq/plone-versions

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. I can assure to use Python 2.6.8rc1 (unknown, Mar 19 2012, 09:27:56) and Plone 4.1.3 (4112). When I debug the error, I realize that portal_state.locale actually returns a string ('de-DE'). But is expecting a locale object that knows the method dates(). The bug can be found here: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10875. I suspect any system or python changes which makes plone behave in that strange way. I am wondering how to achieve any progress.

Comment: The patch published in the ticket helps. ([https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10875](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10875))